# How to pass variables in data flow task SSIS 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, etl, ssis-2008

I am trying to transfer data from one OLEDB connection to another OLEDB. SSIS and SQL Server both 2008 R2. I want to use a variable to load the data for each year (2014, 2015 so on). SQL query in the source is,

```
DECLARE @year int set @year = ?
SELECT [ServiceActivities]
      ,[ServiceID]
      ,[ClientID]
      ,[WorkerID]
      ,[CostCode] 
      ,[ProviderID]
      ,[CostUnit]
      ,[Units]
      ,[OccurrenceDate]
FROM [dbo].[PlannedAppointmentsView] 
WHERE datepart (yy, OccurrenceDate) = @year
```

[image: Source Connection]

But when I click on the Parameters button it throws error, 
[image: Parameters Error]

I have created a variable, not sure if i need one. How can I automate the process to change the variable for each year till current year? Thanks to All.
[image: Variables]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid declaring a variable, just place the `?` in the direct place that you need to pass a parameter.

```
SELECT [ServiceActivities]
  ,[ServiceID]
  ,[ClientID]
  ,[WorkerID]
  ,[CostCode] 
  ,[ProviderID]
  ,[CostUnit]
  ,[Units]
  ,[OccurrenceDate]
FROM [dbo].[PlannedAppointmentsView] 
WHERE datepart (yy, OccurrenceDate) = ?
```

If it still doesn't working, then you must follow the suggestion given to you in this error message.

Just Create a variable (ex: `strQuery`) of type `String`, go to the Properties Tab, change the `Evaluate as expression` property to True, and assign the a similar expression to this variable:

```
"SELECT [ServiceActivities]
  ,[ServiceID]
  ,[ClientID]
  ,[WorkerID]
  ,[CostCode] 
  ,[ProviderID]
  ,[CostUnit]
  ,[Units]
  ,[OccurrenceDate]
FROM [dbo].[PlannedAppointmentsView] 
WHERE datepart (yy, OccurrenceDate) = " + (DT_WSTR,50)@[User::year]
```

after that in the OLEDB Source select `SQL command from variable` option and choose this variable

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Just wanted to share that Hadi's method is working fine. But my main problem was I did not press Parse Query button before Clicking on Parameter button. If anyone having the same issue, please click on the Parse Query first and then click on the Parameter button.

Answer (score 1):

You whould just write like this

```
declare @Year int = ?
```

And then press `Parameters` button and select your desired parameter. Then it will work.

But the right way to do it, is like @Hadi writes in his first comment.